# How to set Copyright version using msbuild?

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli, copyright-display

I am using Jenkins to kick off msbuild to build a project.
I am using Microsift (R) Build Engine Version 2.0.50727.1433.

I have an AssemblyInfo.cs file that appears to contain the following parameters:
AssemblyTitle
AssemblyCompany
AssemblyProduct
AssemblyCopyright
AssemblyVersion
AssemblyFileVersion

The product runs just fine and the version gets set correctly.
I even get a copyright value, it's just not the value specified in the AssemblyInfo.cs file.

Should this be set somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

version.rc file contains the information I was looking for.

Comment: where is this file located? I am also facing the same issue.